# Grid_metrics fails to create grid_metrics.vrt

Tags: r, lidr, gdalbuildvrt, grid-metrics

I need to obtain the metrics for a denoised normalized dataset. This is part of the code that I am using:

```
ctg_denoised <- readLAScatalog("G:/NoBackUp/denoised/")
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg_denoised) <- 10
opt_output_files(ctg_denoised) <- "G:/NoBackUp/metrics/*_metrics"

#METRICS CALCULATION
metrics <- grid_metrics(ctg_denoised, .stdmetrics_z , sqrt(250))
```

When I apply `grid_metrics` to the `catalog` of normalized als data it completes the processing but does not manage to merge all the rasters created into a single `.vrt` file. The `catalog` consists in 1773 files and the result of `grid_metrics` is a list of 1773.
The error after running `grid metrics` says the following and the warnings are repetitive, the repeat the following warnings (1-13):

```
CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\Library\bin\gdalbuildvrt.exe "G:/NoBackUp/grid_metrics.vrt" "G:/NoBackUp/33-1-456-133-76_gf_norm_p95_p95.tif" "G:/NoBackUp/33-1-456-133-77_gf_norm_p95_p95.tif" "G:/NoBackUp/33-1-456-133-79_gf_norm_p95_p95.tif"There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
>Warnings()
1: In min(x, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
7: In min(x, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
8: In max(x, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
9: In min(x, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
10: In max(x, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
11: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
12: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
13: In points2grid(points, tolerance, round) :
  grid has empty column/rows in dimension 1
```

When I run the code with a small dataset the `.vrt` file is created so I don´t know if when treating big dataset is there a specific way of doing it.
So far I have tried to apply info from this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255559/unlist-a-list-of-rasters-in-r) but it didn´t work:

```
library(raster)
r <- stack(metrics[[1]])
for(i in 2:length(metrics)) r <- addLayer(r, metrics[[i]])
class(r)
```

also I have tried from this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308843/calculating-standard-metrics-in-multiple-lidar-files-with-lidr-2-0) but an error occurred:

```
metrics_merge <- do.call(raster::merge, metrics)
Error in as.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: What's the code you are running to get that error? What are the warnings we're not seeing? What do you see if you type `warnings()` like it says in the error message? If it works with a small data set and fails with a big one, where's the point where it fails? Divide your big data into chunks and see where it fails.

Comment: The building of a the virtual mosaic failed for a unknown reason which is impossible to say without a reproducible example. Anyway your rasters were written on disk.

Comment: When I say "divide into chunks" I mean try it with some subset of the catalog: `grid_metrics(ctg_denoised[1:10,], .stdmetrics_z , sqrt(250))` should apply it to the first 10, for example. If that works, then double the "10" until you hit a problem. It could just be one rogue element in your catalog. Hunt it down.

Comment: So, I tried to detect where the problem could be by dividing the `catalog` as @spacedman suggested but the building of the `.vrt` file was succesful for all subsets, it only fails to create it when is applied for the whole `catalog`. When so, the result in the R environment is a `list` of the `.tif` files created in the `opt_output_files(ctg_denoised)`. I have manage to run `gdalbuildvrt` for all the `.tif`s as in this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273018/using-gdalbuildvrt-in-r-gives-warning-message-had-status-1) and it works so i don´t understand what is the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not manage to solve why `grid_metrics` fails to create the `.vrt` file when applied to a big `catalog` but I managed to be able to create the same output. I solved my problem by usig the `gdalUtils` tools from QGIS instead of Anaconda as the error said "`CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\Library\bin\gdalbuildvrt.exe`" and also the `gdalbuildvrt`command failed every time I tried to run it for the denoised normalized catalog, which led me to believed that this Anaconda´s `gdalUtils` was the reason. I changed the directory of `gdalUtils`by following this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328081/how-to-make-gdalutils-package-in-r-to-use-gdal-installed-in-osgeos-directory):

```
library(usethis)
edit_r_profile()
gdalUtils::gdal_setInstallation("C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.4\\bin")
```

Although it did not make `grid_metrics` generate the `.vrt`file, I was able to run `gdalbuildvrt`for the catalog:

```
library(gdalUtils)
vrt <- gdalUtils::gdalbuildvrt(gdalfile = "G:/NoBackUp/metrics/*.tif", 
                               output.vrt = "G:/NoBackUp/metrics/grid_metrics.vrt"
                               , overwrite = TRUE)

vrt.file <- stack("G:/NoBackUp/metrics/grid_metrics.vrt")
```

It takes considerably longer to create this `.vrt` file by this method and to read it as a stack or brick also takes really long but it manages to create the same output.

Comment: The next time please mention that you are not working in a regular environment but within a container. I'm not surprised it does not work in a container. Using `gdalUtils::gdal_setInstallation` is probably the good answer. Then, using `gdalUtils::gdalbuildvrt` is exacly what is done internally in `lidR`.

Comment: I was not aware that I was working within a container. I do not really know what that means

Comment: You are working within anaconda. anaconda is a kind of container of something similar I don't really know actually. What I know is that you are not the first one to encounter troubles because not mastering enough the tools you are using. Imo a regular R installation is preferable if you are not 100% sure of what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Unfortunetly I can not do much about it because I do not have complete access to the computer I work with. Most softwares are pre-installed or have default sets when installing that I can´t change. Can I ask you something else about the processing time? can you imagine why does it takes so long (like 3 times more) when I create the `.vrt` file in comparison to when it is created with `grid_metrics`?

Comment: I don't know. I guess it depends on the size of the raster and I guess that gdalbuildvrt takes time. This should be reproduced and benchmarked to be answered. 3 times seems to be a lot.